# How to use awk to change one column of a line(date)

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to create a script that will create a log file in which there are two columns: first is date of editing and second is path to textfile, which was edited. How can I change the first column of a line, but keep the second column containing the path? I have tried 
`awk '$2=="$path{$1=$date}"' logfile.txt` where $path contains path of the file, but that doesn't change the date.

Thanks in advance.

logfile:

```
20.03.18.19.08.56 /home/ubuntu/Desktop
```

now lets say i edited something and now the logfile should look like:

```
21.03.18.19.08.56 /home/ubuntu/Desktop
```

Comment: lowcase_m, kindly confirm once if you have already existing file or you want to create a new file with current path and date's details? If you have already existing file then kindly do post the samples in your post.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I am sorry, i have corrected my mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can pass the values as awk variables

```
$ awk -v date="$date" -v path="$path" '$2==path{$1=date}1' file > newfile
```